# How to use setcsvcontrol()

Tags: php, csv, delimiter

Good morning,

I'm developing a script to create a csv file. My problem is the delimiter of csv file, I need to use ";".

I read that I have to use "setcsvcontrol()" but I'm trying to use it and I haven't had any results.

This is a part of my script:

```
$create = fopen($fecha."p.csv", "a");
$file = new SplFileObject($fecha."p.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$file->setCsvControl(';');

foreach($cadena as $fields){    

    fputcsv($create,$fields);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SplFileObject::setCsvControl()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.setcsvcontrol.php) only affects the object on which it was called, i.e. the `$file` object in your case. It does not affect the `$create` object that you got from `fopen`, even though both objects operate on the same file.

Either write to the `$create` object using [`fputcsv($handle, $fields, $delimiter, $enclosure)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), passing `$create` as first argument and the desired delimiter and enclosure as third and fourth arguments, or call [`$file->fputcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fputcsv.php). In the latter case, you have to [create the `SplFileObject`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.construct.php) as writable using a suitable `$open_mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Your not passing the delimiter to `fputcsv`;

```
fputcsv($create,$fields, ";");
```

you can also safely remove

```
$file = new SplFileObject($fecha."p.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$file->setCsvControl(';');
```

if you must use the `SplFileObject` Then change your code to.

```
$file = new SplFileObject("data.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::WRITE_CSV);
$file->setCsvControl(';');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $file->fputcsv($row);
}
```

Comment: There is no `WRITE_CSV` constant.